# SQL Logarithmic Exponent Calculations Log(Exp(Today-FirstSeen/365))

Tags: sql, sql-server, exponential, getdate

I am attempting to calculate Log(exp(Today-(FirstTimeSeen/365))) using the code listed below.

When executing the query I receive the error message listed below.

`Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type float.`

I have broken the query apart and determined that the error is related to the `exp(getdate())` calculation.

```
    select LOG(exp(cast(convert(float,getdate())-(convert(float,[FirstSeen])/365) AS DECIMAL (10,5)))) from FindingsByDate
```

Comment: Why do you try converting date to float? You can easily get by with first calculating `DATEDIFF` of the two dates and convert that result to float

Comment: You're only dividing your second date with 365 which probably results in a pretty big exponent.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(getdate()-[FirstSeen])/365` instead of `getdate()-([FirstSeen]/365)`?  Also you should be using `DATEDIFF` so you can specify that you want the difference in days rather than relying on the subtraction operator.

Comment: Plus `log` and `exp` are inverses, so they would cancel each other out.  It looks like you have translated a formula incorrectly.

Comment: It seems clear this was someone trying to use math to do DATEDIFF -- just use DATEDIFF

Comment: I'm actually trying to mimic something that was calculated in excel 

        =EXP((TODAY()-[@[first_found_datetime]])/365)